# how to get/trigger check box 's Jquery executed it self after page loaded

Tags: java, jquery, html, events, web

so I have few check boxs line up with some JQuery event/logic when user click on it.

however, when the page load I have a trigger Jquery event, which makes one of the check box by ID

```
$("#ro0").trigger('click');
```

and It checked the box but I also want is (it will execute the jquery behind #ro0)

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name=Main]').click(function(){ alert('thanks you for taking ur time to answering my question! :) ');    }
```

Comment: Are you running the .trigger before the event is attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the trigger occurs **after** the click handler is attached

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){ alert('thanks you for taking...');}); 
$("input[type=checkbox]").trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox"/>
```